# How to export the unfolded image I'm seeing in the UV Image Editor as an SVG?

Tags: uv-image-editor

[image]I'm wanting to convert a 3D concave cylinder into a 2D image. I've brought it into Blender as an STL, generated a UV Image, and added a material. Looks good. I'm just learning Blender. So search results seemed to indicate that Paper Model add-in was the way to go to get 3D > 2D > SVG export.

But I can't keep it from unwrapping mesh triangles into a thousand tiny, separate packed islands. When I use Export Paper Model, I don't get what I see in the UV/Image editor: the mesh flattened. Instead, each triangle has been separated out and packed with like kind, each with their own little numbered tabs. This would be really cool for creating paper models. I get that.

But I need bigger islands: I need exactly what I'm seeing in the UV Image Editor screen. Any way I can just export that to SVG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the UV-Layout as .svg file. In the UV-Editor, go to *UV > Export UV Layout*. Then select the file format as .svg.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. But I'm not seeing the UV Image menu item. I've updated my question to include a screenshot of my menus. I have an "Image" menu item, but on selecting that, the resulting dialog box does not give an option for SVG. How do I get all the menu items you have?

Comment: @theship Right. You have to switch to edit mode in the 3D view and select all vertices. Then the options should appear in the UV Editor.

Comment: That'll do it! Thanks much.